# I am trying to write an OpenAPI description with below details

Tags: openapi, swagger-ui

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Core Domain Mock Server
  description: TODO Description
  version: v1
servers:
- url: http://localhost:5001/sa
  description: Dev
- url: http://localhost:5001/sa
  description: Test
security:
  - BasicAuth: []
  - BearerAuth: []
  - ApiKeyAuth: []
paths:
  /another-endpoint:
    get:
        summary: Another Endpoint
        security: 
          - BasicAuth: []
        parameters:
          - name: apiKey
            in: header
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
        responses:
          '200':
            description: OK 
            content:
               application/json:
                example: {"apiKey": "sampleKey123"}

components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
    BearerAuth: 
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: X-API-KEY
```

using try-it-out, execute an endpoint provide credentials and get an authKey as an response and store the authKey anywhere and send it again to an endpoint through header. write whole code in yaml file only. is it possible, if yes how and if not then what is the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic representation of your request

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: My API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:5001
    description: Development server
paths:
  '/users':
    get:
      summary: Get all users
      operationId: getAllUsers
      security:
        - ApiKeyAuth: []
        - BearerAuth: []
      tags:
        - users
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
  '/auth': 
    get:
      summary: Get auth token
      operationId: getAuthToken
      security:
        - BasicAuth: []
      tags:
        - users
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
  securityScheme:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
    BearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: X-API-KEY
```

Comment: any suggestion to solve the issue?

Comment: which issue do you have?